# Pull top div down to the bottom when bottom div disappears

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky

Currently, `.div1` floats `50px` above the bottom of the video frame. When `.div2` (the controls bar) disappears, I want `.div1` to move down and stick to the new bottom.

Just like how subtitles are handled by Netflix' video player, when the controls bar disappears, the subtitles should be "pulled" down to the bottom.
That is what I am looking for.
[Test](http://test.movstream.dk)

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.out {
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  height: 560px;
  background-color: #000;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -500px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -280px;
}
.div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
}
.div2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please try to explain/clarify further. As it's currently written, it's quite hard to understand what you're asking

Comment: For the red div to be at bottom, you'll need to change your css for div1 to - bottom: 0px;

Comment: I want the red div to stick to bottom when blue div disappears. and then when blue dis appears again on mouse move or something, then the red div need to be on top of the blue div again.

Comment: So essentially you want to make the height of the top div responsively fill 100% of the available space left over from the static-height bottom div.

Comment: That sounds like it, and how would you do this? when I give div1 a height of 100% then div2 is overlapping div1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By toggling the visibility of the blue div, you can also change the css `bottom` to move back and forth.
I've put in a button to trigger the event, you can use whatever (hover something, click something else, etc.)

```
var flip = 0;
$('#btnChange').on('click',function(){
    $('.div2').toggle(0,function(){
        if(flip++ % 2 === 0){
            $('.div1').css("bottom", "0px");
        } else{
            $('.div1').css("bottom", "50px");
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/acsvrzLf/

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, that would be:

```
$(".out").find(".div2").hide().end().find(".div1").css({"bottom": "0px"});
```

that works for your test page once you have included jQuery.